# Can't find element by Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Lately I have been learning Python scraping. The part of the source code:

```
div class='search__grid'>
  <div class="photos">
    <div class='photos__column'>
      <div class='hide-featured-badge hide-favorite-badge'>
        <article class='photo-item photo-item--overlay'>
          <a class="js-photo-link photo-item__link" href="/photo/person-holding-black-ceramic-pig-coin-bank-3943723/">    
            <img srcset="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3943723/pexels-photo-3943723.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=1&amp;w=500 1x, https://images.pexels.com/photos/3943723/pexels-photo-3943723.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=2&amp;w=500 2x" 
            class="photo-item__img" alt="Person Holding Black Ceramic Pig Coin Bank" data-image-width="3811" data-image-height="5716" 
            data-big-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3943723/pexels-photo-3943723.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;h=750&amp;w=1260" />
```

I want to collect the the image link in `img.srcset.data-large-src`. However, I couldn't find the `div` element by using:

```
find_element_by_class_name('search__grid')
```

nor `by_tag_name(div.search_grid)` nor `by_css_selector('divsearch_grid')`. For example, an error occurred as I used `by_class_name` as below...

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".search__grid"}
```

I didn't even use the css selector...!

Another question is how could I extract only the `data-big-src` link from the `srcset` attribute?

I look forward to your opinions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it a public url?

Answer (score 0):

firstly get the img element

```
imgElement = driver.find_element_by_class_name('photo-item__img');
```

or by XPAHT

```
imgElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains(@class,'photo-item__img')]")
```

second, go for the attribute data-big-src

```
textElement = imgElement.get_attribute('data-big-src');
```

Comment: The first one gave: `Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".photo-item__img"}`
The second one gave: `Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//img[contains(@class,'photo-item__img')]"}` ... It's really weird, I have succedded in a couple of websites but this one just won't work

Comment: updated my answer for xpath. If you want you can share the link to see exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like the following to get the srcset value.

```
imgElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//img[class='photo-item__img']")))
print(imgElement.get_attribute('srcset'))
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

The image link can be found within `srcset` as well as within `data-big-src` attribute, to print the value of the *image link* you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and *srcset* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.search__grid > div.photos > div.photos__column a.js-photo-link.photo-item__link[href^='/photo/person-holding-black-ceramic-pig-coin-bank'] > img"))).get_attribute("data-clipboard-text"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *data-big-src* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='search__grid']/div[@class='photos']/div[@class='photos__column']//a[@class='js-photo-link photo-item__link' and starts-with(@href, '/photo/person-holding-black-ceramic-pig-coin-bank')]/img"))).get_attribute("data-big-src"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)